# How do the source and destination rectangles work in SDL_RenderCopy()?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have been confused on this issue ever since I started using renderers. Any help?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy it's pretty clear what the rect params are used for. They let you specify what part of the texture you want to copy from source to destionation (or NULL for all of it).

Comment: I have read the documentation for the function. I have still had difficulty trying to understand it. I was hoping you could try to explain it in Layman’s terms. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I think the best way to get a good understanding of the function is to play around with it and do some experiments. Try loading an image and test different sizes for the src and dst rects and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

basically the source rect is just a selection tool that start from x,y = 0,0 (editable) of the png or some file, until w,h (some number, some number) (also editable) of the png file.